# Quais são as dependências que preciso adicionar às pastas do Glassfish?

Tags: java-ee, hibernate, jboss, glassfish

Fala galera!

Estou utilizando no meu projeto JSF o framework Hibernate. 
No computador que eu estou desenvolvendo está tudo certo, rodando, porém, 
quando tento implantar no servidor glassfish em outra máquina começa a dar uns erros dizendo que as as classes não possuem métodos X e Y e etc.
Minha dúvida é, se eu já adicionei os jars na buildpath do projeto, eu preciso inserí-las também na pasta do glassfish? Em qual pasta seria? Adiciono só as bibliotecas do Hibernate ou as do jBoss também?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

É necessário que você **encapsule todas as libs externas** que você utiliza em seu projeto, ou seja, vincule-as em sua geração do build, ou utilize um gerenciador automatizado de build (Maven, Ant, Gradle, etc), pessoalmente recomendo o Maven pela facilidade de uso.

Caso deseja mais detalhes:

1. Incluir no glassfish as libs:

Copiar as libs para o diretório domain1\lib\classes, com essa ação, os JARs entrarão diretamente ao classpath

2. Incluir os JARs na pasta LIB em seu EAR

Copiar os JARS para a pasta LIB do projeto (APP-INF\lib)

Para mais detalhes sobre como utilizar o maven, acesse a seguinte url: https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/